# URL decryption error using DES

Tags: java, security, url, encryption, des

Am being able to encrypt/decrypt my URL successfully before sending the url in an email, but after passing the URL and retrieving it am decrypting the encrypted part of the URL, its not being decrypted correctly. Am getting strange characters after decryption, for example:

my text before encryption:

```
dkjkb7i8doprgeh521tbbdll9r-Sat Apr 12 17:21:01 EEST 2014
```

my text after:

```
decryption:ziUO5baLOpFaOfWBtMOLhrRBR2ucXnxFHbA2KoRUVVQst6oDqUrGIU04qey4xU6haNvyp18+BROzadH6MXNxKA==
```

URL decryption after sending the url,decrypted text after sending url :

```
dkjkb7i8doprgeh521tbbdll9r-Sat Apr 12 17:21:01 **E[???xno**
```

this is my DES class that i use for encryption, decryption:

```
package com;

import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESKeySpec;
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

public class DESEncryption {

    private static final String UNICODE_FORMAT = "UTF8";
    public static final String DES_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME = "DES";
    private KeySpec myKeySpec;
    private SecretKeyFactory mySecretKeyFactory;
    private Cipher cipher;
    byte[] keyAsBytes;
    private String myEncryptionKey;
    private String myEncryptionScheme;
    SecretKey key;

    public DESEncryption() throws Exception {
        myEncryptionKey = "ThisIsSecretEncryptionKey";
        myEncryptionScheme = DES_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME;
        keyAsBytes = myEncryptionKey.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
        myKeySpec = new DESKeySpec(keyAsBytes);
        mySecretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(myEncryptionScheme);
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(myEncryptionScheme);
        key = mySecretKeyFactory.generateSecret(myKeySpec);
    }

    /**
     * Method To Encrypt The String
     */
    public String encrypt(String unencryptedString) {
        String encryptedString = null;
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] plainText = unencryptedString.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
            byte[] encryptedText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);
            BASE64Encoder base64encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
            encryptedString = base64encoder.encode(encryptedText);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return encryptedString;
    }

    /**
     * Method To Decrypt An Ecrypted String
     */
    public String decrypt(String encryptedString) {
        String decryptedText = null;
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            BASE64Decoder base64decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
            byte[] encryptedText = base64decoder.decodeBuffer(encryptedString);
            byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(encryptedText);
            decryptedText = bytes2String(plainText);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return decryptedText;
    }

    /**
     * Returns String From An Array Of Bytes
     */
    private static String bytes2String(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            stringBuffer.append((char) bytes[i]);
        }
        return stringBuffer.toString();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base 64 utilizes the `/` and `+` characters. You need to do either one of the following:

1. URL-encode your base 64 string;
2. Use a [base 64 variant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Implementations_and_history) that is safe for URL's.

The first one is easier to code but may be less efficient than the second one (if there are many `/` and `+` characters in the encoding).

Note that you can use a simple string replacement to utilize #2, so it is not *that* hard.

Comment: Also note that this is only a direct answer. I cringe when I look at the use of cryptography and Java in the question. Maybe supply this to the codereview stackexchange website as well.